# How to optimize the treatment time in python for loop?

Tags: python

I need some help to optimize the treatment time in my for loop for filtering images in real time so I use the equation int the loop as shown in the code. But when I launch my program it takes about 1 or 2 seconds to filter one image.

Note : size of my images is about 1280x920 pixels

Thanks at advance

```
def filtre_line(image,H,L,w):
    im_filtred=np.zeros((H,L),dtype=float)
    for i in range(H):
       for j in range(L):
          if j>w and j<L-w:
             im_filtred[i][j]=np.multiply(2,(image[i]  [j]).astype(np.float32))-abs((image[i][j-w]).astype(np.float32)+(image[i][j+w]).astype(np.float32))-abs((image[i][j-w]).astype(np.float32)-(image[i][j+w]).astype(np.float32))
    for r in im_filtred:
        image = r 
    return image
```

Comment: This might be better to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/